# How do I use R to manipulate/pivot this set?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset as follows:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 4 |
| a | 4 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 6 |
| b | 7 |
| b | 9 |
| b | 7 |
| b | 7 |

I am looking to generate the following output:

Output

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 6 |
| b | 7 |
| b | 9 |

Can someone please assist with this? Thank you!

I usually do this on excel but I am trying to automate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unique` on the dataset

```
unique(df1)
```

Comment: Wow. That simple huh? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

! -> remove

[] -> inside the data frame, left of the comman means rows, right columns,

So, the code say: I want the df1 without duplicated rows.

So, try this.

```
    df1 <- df1[!duplicated(df1),]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).